# Enable HTML input in jointjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jointjs

I have tried doing the example as per the tutorial in JointJs. However there are two problems :-

1. I am not able to create a second custom element in jointJS. i dont understand how to have two types of html templates. not all of my shapes are the same html code.
2. i can work around the above problem by having html as content in joint.shapes.basic.textblock. However, no amount of fiddling with pointer-events in CSS seems to work. the textbox is not editable.

The lack of documentation is frustrating. Please Help

Edit:
The code i am using for the textblock is :

```
var el2 = new joint.shapes.basic.TextBlock({
            position: { x:0, y:600 },
            size: { width: 500, height: 70 },
            attrs: { rect: { fill: 'transparent' }},
            content: "<div class="html-element"><label>Enter Value</label><input type="text" id="input1" /></div>
    }); graph.addCells([el2]);
```

Comment: Share some code you tried/attempted.

Comment: @ThatAwesomeCoder I have used the exact code as in the tutorial @ http://jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements to create custom elements